# Unable to save the data from ionic to mongodb : MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to post some data from ionic to MongoDB but it is not getting posted I mean is not recognizing the url in the routes page. But when I'm trying to post the data from the `postman` data is getting saved but not through the ionic.

```
let selected = {
      companyTitle : jobitem.company,
      jobTitle : jobitem.jobtitle,
      location : jobitem.location,
      date: appliedDate,
      id: userId
    }
    console.log(selected);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/jobApplied',selected,{headers: headers})
```

The above code is from the ionic `ts` file. The below code is from the routes.js js file

```
router.post('/jobApplied', function(req,res) {
  console.log('posting');
  appliedJobs.create({
    companyTitle: req.body.companyTitle,
    jobTitle: req.body.jobTitle,
    location: req.body.location,
    date: req.body.date,
    userId: req.body.id
  },function(err,list) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err getting list '+ err);
    } else {
      //res.json(list);
      return res.json(list) }
  }
  );
});
```

I have used the same url in the `postman`

> http://localhost:3000/api/jobApplied

but the data is not getting posted. What might be the problem & How can I solve it?

Comment: did you check for CORS? where does your ionic application works?

Comment: Yes, I can make other requests(http) fine but only this particular request does not work.  ionic is on pc(local server)

Comment: don't count postman. Postman does not restrict CORS requests. If you are using modern browsers to test your ionic app, the issue is most probably CORS. what is the error message ?

Comment: Can you share full code that is relevant to the issue?

Comment: There is no error message. There is no action taking place in the `nodeJS`